# Understanding a selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

Can anyone explain this specific javaScript selector:

```
document.querySelectorAll("div[class^='tile']");
```

specifically the `^=` part?

Comment: This is a regular CSS selector. JavaScript doesn't really have anything to do with it besides making use of CSS selectors via the selectors API.

Answer (score 6):

It's [CSS3's "attribute begins with" selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors)

Therefore this selects all divs that have the class attribute beginning with "title"

Answer (score 0):

It means that the attribute on the left should start with the value on the right.

So `div class="tile0"`, `div class="tiles"`, etc. will be matched by the selector.

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelectorAll()` accept queries like CSS selectors to select DOM elements. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.querySelectorAll) is the best reference for understanding how it works. `querySelector`s are part of DOM Selector API, For full specification go [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/).

This code that you included here used attribute selector query. The attribute selectors are not limited to class. You can use any attribute that you want (and is available) to select. For example if you have this HTML:

`<label for="myInput">My Lable</label>`

then this selector will select your element:

`document.querySelector('input[for="myInput"]');`

The operator between attribute an value can be following:

`[attr=value]` : Selects element that have attribute completely equal to given value

`[attr*=value]` : Selects elements that have attribute that **contain** given value. Like `mvalue`, `value`, `valueone`....

`[attr~=value]` : Same as `*=` but the `value` should be separated with space. Like `my value`

`[attr$=value]` : Ends with `value`

`[attr^=value]` : Starts with `value`

`[attr!=value]` : Not equal to `value`